# Laravel Datatable: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: json, ajax, datatable

I'm trying to get data from my database to the datatable. This is my script for the datatable:

```
var table = $('#teamTable').DataTable({
         dom: 'Bfrtip', 
         pageLength: 25,   
         "ajax":{
            url :"/teamsPopulate",  
            dataType: 'json',
         },
         columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "name" },
                { data: "parent_id" },
                { data: "created_at" },
                { data: "update_at" }],
         serverSide     : true,
        "bProcessing": true, 
        select: 'multiple',
        responsive: true,
        altEditor: true,     
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Add',
          name: 'add'
        },
        {
          extend: 'selected',  
          text: 'Edit',
          name: 'edit'        
        }]
 });
```

This is my script for the controller

```
  public function getTeamContents(){
    $teams = Team::all();
    return response ()->json( $teams );
  }
```

And this is my view

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="teamTable">  
<thead>
  <tr> 
      <th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
  </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>                           
</tbody>
</table>
```

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: check if your ajax request don't have any error(s)

Comment: this is the error the console gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at _fnAjaxUpdateDraw (jquery.dataTables.js:4104)
    at jquery.dataTables.js:3950
    at callback (jquery.dataTables.js:3842)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.js:3872)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

Comment: what I mean is the ajax request go to 

click f12 then togo network see your ajax request

Comment: teams populate says [{"id":1,"name":"top","parent_id":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"name":"second to top","parent_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":3,"name":"something","parent_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":4,"name":"Team Golden State","parent_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":120,"name":"lol","parent_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-22 04:47:01","updated_at":"2017-03-22 04:47:01"},{"id":121,"name":"kjjb","parent_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-22 04:47:36","updated_at":"2017-03-22 04:47:36"}, etc

Comment: can u put the headers in your table and check once, <thead>
  <tr> 
      <th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>parent_id</th><th>created_at</th><th>updat‌​ed_at</th>
  </tr>   
</thead>

Comment: @BasantaMatia it still doesn't work </3 it's the same error